# CKEditor change my html

Tags: html, asp.net, ckeditor

I want to create 2 span's, first with big-text and the second with small text
[image]

after saving its generate another html

[image]

how to save my original html, how disable auto correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable the autocorrection. There are two reasons why:

- CKEditor needs a valid HTML which also has to be filtered in a special way, so it can be edited in `contenteditable` element without problems.
- CKEditor passes data through browsers (because `contenteditable` is a native feature) which also correct some of mistakes, but usually browsers are more forgiving.